# Is there a way to access a folder and it's files from a different network?

Tags: files, filesystem, file-sharing

I am migrating my photo library from Google Photos to my local Pictures directory on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS system. However, I was wondering if there was a way to view those photos on a different computer on a different network (e.g. a friend's house). Just curious because I saw this: https://www.vlchelp.com/remote-control-smartphone-browser/ and https://forums.tomsguide.com/faq/how-to-stream-videos-over-the-internet-with-vlc.23235/. And, according to the VLC for iOS app, it says I can stream from SMB, FTP, UPnP/DLNA (are those servers?). I'm looking for a step-by-step guide since I'm really a novice in this area.

Comment: Look up how to turn on File Sharing. That will enable you to reach your files from elsewhere in your house. Next, look up how to set up Port Forwarding on your router. Then will enable you to reach your files from across the internet. Warning: Bad Guys' automated tools may quickly locate your system, and they are very good at breaking in without being detected. So also look up how to secure your network login by using SSH keys instead of passwords. Finally, look up how to make regular backups...in case the Bad Guys succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that, but you are at that point, self hosting your own content. Your home internet probably close those ports by default, since it is a fairly big security risk. On most occasions, you can open them, and get around the dynamic ip that is the norm those days. Some providers might prohibit you from self hosting, as they sell a more expensive business plan that allows you to do that.

Take a look at [nextcloud](https://nextcloud.com/), specifically nextcloud photos:

https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/14/user_manual/files/gallery_app.html

Now, you don't necessarily need anything like that. A simple ssh connection is enough, if you open the ports on your router, redirect them to the internal ip from your home computer and know what external ip your home network is using at that point.

**But please, read carefully on the security issues, concerns and best practices before doing anything like that. If you have no idea what you are doing, you are opening yourself for plenty of trouble.**

Comment: This is good information. However, I don't think I'll do that after all. I was migrating from Google Photos because I cared about security, so I won't do this.

Comment: Yeah, that's usually more work than it is worth for most people. But you don't need to start like that. Start playing inside your home network, where the environment is much safer. Enable ssh server, go into those machines. Try watching a video that is on your computer from the VLC app on your phone, try using an old laptop or a raspberry pi as a backup server for the files on your main computer, etc. Baby steps first. Although not necessarily worth it, it can be a fun learning experience.

Answer (score 1):

For that and even copying files between computers I just use dropbox. Its in the standard software repo.

You can share files with the standard desktop and all ways mentioned in the question, but just local network and wifi, not over the internet.

Dropbox will have you sharing in minutes and integrates with the desktop and file explorer. Its easy, fast and free.

Comment: I don't think that's what he was asking. He asking if he can access those files, stored on his own computer, not on a third party server. For the purposes of his question, dropbox is exactly the same as the google drive that he is migrating from